# Serverless Typescript Rest API with Typeorm and Express.js

Tags: typescript, express, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, typeorm

I'm new to Node.js.
Currently I have a working microservices architecture based system working in Heroku and my goal is to change our infrastructure to AWS Lambda using Serverless with Typescript while also switching from Sequelize to TypeORM and keep using express.js as the Restful API framework.

I've tried to make all of those things work together and eventually when running a basic GET request against my service (running with sls offline), i receive `Cannot Get /documents`

I'm sure that the problem lies in `app.ts`.
The routes are empty, but I don't know how to fix that.

I've tried many other options, but this one seems to work well with the DB, it even automatically migrated my Entity and created the table correctly in my DB.

Any hint or guidance would be appreciated.

My code:

```
//serverless.ts

import type { Serverless } from 'serverless/aws';

const serverlessConfiguration: Serverless = {
  service: {
    name: 'iod-typeorm-test',
    // app and org for use with dashboard.serverless.com
    // app: your-app-name,
    // org: your-org-name,
  },
  frameworkVersion: '2',
  custom: {
    webpack: {
      webpackConfig: './webpack.config.js',
      includeModules: true
    }
  },
  // Add the serverless-webpack plugin
  plugins: ['serverless-webpack','serverless-offline'],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    profile: '01iod',
    region: 'eu-central-1',
    runtime: 'nodejs12.x',
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
    },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
    },
  },
  functions: {
    hello: {
      handler: 'handler.hello',
      events: [
        {
          http: {
            method: 'get',
            path: '/documents',
          }
        },
        {
          http: {
            method: 'post',
            path: '/documents',
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

```
//ormconfig.json
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "root",
   "password": "password",
   "database": "myService",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": true,
   "uuidExtension": true,
   "keepConnectionAlive": true,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

```
//handler.ts
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createServer, proxy } from 'aws-serverless-express';
import { Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { configureApp } from './app';

const binaryMimeTypes: string[] = [
  'application/json'
];
const app = configureApp();
const server = createServer(app, undefined, binaryMimeTypes);

export const hello = (event: any, context: Context) =>
  proxy(server, event, context);
```

```
//app.ts
import * as express from 'express';
import { json, urlencoded } from 'body-parser';
import * as cors from 'cors';
import { eventContext } from 'aws-serverless-express/middleware';
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {Routes} from "./src/routes/routes"
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

export function configureApp() {
  const app = express();

  createConnection().then(async connection => {

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(json());
    app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(eventContext());

    // create express app
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
  
    // register express routes from defined application routes
    Routes.forEach(route => {
        (app as any)[route.method](route.route, (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
            const result = (new (route.controller as any))[route.action](req, res, next);
            if (result instanceof Promise) {
                result.then(result => result !== null && result !== undefined ? res.send(result) : undefined);
  
            } else if (result !== null && result !== undefined) {
                res.json(result);
            }
        });
    });

    if (!connection.isConnected) {
      connection = await connection.connect();
    }

  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  

  return app;
}
```

```
//./src/routes/routes
import {DocumentController} from "../controller/DosumentsController";

export const Routes = [{
    method: "get",
    route: "/documents",
    controller: DocumentController,
    action: "all"
}, {
    method: "get",
    route: "/documents/:id",
    controller: DocumentController,
    action: "one"
}, {
    method: "post",
    route: "/documents",
    controller: DocumentController,
    action: "save"
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually was running into this same issue and it took me forever to solve. The issue is that you need to initialize the database at the start of every lambda invocation. In your case, your configureApp method returns a promise, which is not being waited for prior to starting the server.

I'm not entirely sure on the solution using Serverless AWS, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
export const hello = async (event: any, context: Context) => {
  const app = await configureApp()
  const server = createServer(app, undefined, binaryMimeTypes);
  proxy(server, event, context);
}
```